# Using await/async with observables in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to make an api call and assign the result using async code. here is what i have.

```
public async getInfoFeed(): Promise<Feed> {
    let returnVal: Feed;
    await this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe( 
            data => returnVal = data, 
            err => console.log(err)
        )

        return returnVal;
}

var info = await this.getInfoFeed();
console.log(info);
```

by the time the code completes, info is 'undefined'. How can i make this method asynchronous?

Comment: You can only `await` a promise. Surely there's some kind of `.toPromise` method on observables?

Comment: Not sure about the duplicate tag, the other answer has no reference to async/await. May have been better to post an actual answer than an implied one.